# maven transitive dependency wrong version

Tags: maven, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I deployed a jar A with the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
  <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I have another project B and project C both with dependency to A. So the structure is as following:

```
B -> A -> reactor-core

C -> A -> reactor-core
```

The problem is the version of reactor-core is different in project B and project C. In B, its version is 2.0.8. In C it's 3.3.1 .
In fact, I have excluded the version 2.0.8 in project A. I don't know why it still appears.

Comment: exclude should work. make sure delete target before build or use `maven clean`

Comment: @Bejond I have tried, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use excludes. They are hard to manage.

Look at the dependency tree (`mvn dependency:tree`). You will `reactor-core` at different places with different versions. Maven "mediates" this tree and chooses the "nearest" version.

If you don't want this behaviour (actually, you often don't want that), make an entry in `<dependencyManagement>` with the correct version. This will override all transitive versions and you get the version you want. You do *not* need exclusions for that.

Comment: Hi, I have add <dependencyManagement> with the correct version to project A. But when B has dependency to jar A. the version is still 2.0.8. Do you know how to make the deployed jar have the correct version?

Comment: The dependencyManagement overrides all transitive versions. Where exactly does the 2.0.8 come from? From a parent POM?

Comment: In A, there is a dependency rsocket-core, which has a transitive dependency to version 2.0.8

Comment: You need to add `<dependency>
  <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
  <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>` to the dependencyManagement of B.

Comment: yes, this will work. But I don't want any project that depends on A to add this dependencyManagement. How can I ensure that A contains only version 3.3.1?

Comment: If A has a direct dependency on 3.3.1, then this will override all transitive dependencies of A.

Comment: Maybe we are missing something important in your POM here. Because if B depends on A and A has a direct dependency on reactor-core:3.3.1, then B will have a dependency on reactor-core:3.3.1 unless B has another dependency D that depends on a different reactor-core version or B has some dependencyManagement that overrides this.